# How to do i click on the Second link in the table, those values are changing dynamically in Selenium RC Server

Tags: html, eclipse, selenium, selenium-rc

How I click on the second link XYZ STORES.

How I print the text "Store XYZ address"

How I click on the second link ABC STORES.

How I print the text "Store ABC address"

Where link dynamically, address text and store name change dynamically. How I click on the link even no id or class is on the table. All data in the table form. This is the HTML and Please help in the RC server coding form:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <a href="/pages/dealer-detail?dealer=XYZ STORES&amp;state=Chandigarh&amp;city=Chandigarh">XYZ STORES</a>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Store XYZ address </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <a href="/pages/dealer-detail?dealer=ABC STORES&amp;state=Chandigarh&amp;city=Chandigarh">ABC STORES</a>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Store ABC address </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here links are changing dynamically, none is static link, link name, and data

Comment: Why Selenium-RC? It has been deprecated for several years now.

Comment: Thanks from now i will.

Comment: @Subh hey subh can you help me in this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well this is the xpath that you get from your given website:

```
selenium.click("/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span/a");
```

On this you are able to click
and 
You have to print the the data by storing the data in the string variable and print the string vriable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below xpaths for the respective clicking and retrieving text (**I have worked it out as per the xpath you've provided**):

**1-** For Clicking on the link `'XYZ STORES'`:

```
//a[.='XYZ STORES']
```

**2-** For retrieving the text `'Store XYZ address'`

```
//a[.='XYZ STORES']/ancestor::tr/td[2]
```

**3-** For Clicking on the link `'ABC STORES'`:

```
//a[.='ABC STORES']
```

**4-** For retrieving the text `'Store ABC address'`

```
//a[.='ABC STORES']/ancestor::tr/td[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. Since I see no id or class I think an XPath should work nicely. 
In Chrome or Firefox right click were this href html is located and copy the XPath.

```
selenium.click("copiedXpath");
```

Hopefully this works, Selenium-RC is depreciated now. Tasks such as these would be easier on the newer Selenium Webdriver, Selenium IDE, or Selenium Remote Control.